# For each php variable in jquery script

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter

In my php I have a for each loop that sets the order id. I wish to run a jquery function for each of the orders but I cannot get it to work.

HTML

```
<i id="<?php echo "edit".$row['order_id'] ?>" class="fa fa-pencil-square-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
```

Jquery

```
$("<?php echo "#edit".$row['order_id'] ?>").click(function(){....}
```

The function runs but only for the second option. The question is how to pass the specific id variable to the script since the $row['order_id'] changes everytime and the script (I assume gets the final value)

Comment: Are both HTML and Jquery snippets contained in a `.php` script?

Comment: Yes they are at the same script. Actually the event gets triggered but only when I select the second button. It must be an issue with how I set my id's

Comment: @OluwafemiSule made some edits

Comment: How about assigning a common class to the icons and using the class name as a selector?

Comment: @OluwafemiSule I need to run the function for each specific item in the for each loop

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe what you need is a data property (placed via php) in your html, and then to read that property in a single event listener.  For example:

```
<i data-orderid="<?php echo $row['order_id']; ?>" class="edits fa fa-pencil-square-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
```

And then

```
$('.edits').click(function(event) {
    var rowId = $(event.target).data('orderid');
    // use the variable...
});
```